# Multiple sql commands in one single connection C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core

I have to run different sql statement in one connection may be 5-6. Example:

1. Checking some condition in a table.
2. Updating another table on the basis of value received from first command.
3. Inserting new data to some other table on the basis of result of first command.

All of the command contains parameterized query.

This is how I am approaching to it. Is is good approach? Does this create multiple round trips to database? Or am I wrong on round trips. Please suggest me on this.

```html
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection (connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand command1 = new NpgsqlCommand (commandText1, connection))
    {
      //select
    }
    using (NpgsqlCommand command2 = new NpgsqlCommand (commandText2, connection))
    {
      //update
    }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)

Comment: Alternatively you can put some of the logic into a [stored procedure[(https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-stored-procedures/) which would allow you to make one round trip to/from the database. If that is worth it or not depends on both the complexity of the logic as well as the frequency this method is called.

Comment: Assuming `NpgsqlConnection` is well-behaved, your example code will, in fact, run `n` commands using one connection to the DB.  However, I second @Igor's comment that you consider converting this logic into a stored procedure.

Comment: It carries a lot of business logic and can't be directly exposed in store procedures.

Comment: Then there is nothing of substance left to discuss. As such any answer would be rooted in either speculation or in opinion.

Comment: @VictorWilson 
Can running n number of commands cause any serious problem in performance?

Comment: You can refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999452/npgsql-one-connection-multiple-commands